# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Mediainfo

Tags: python, popen, mediainfo

I'm trying to find out if file is a video. Currently trying with pymediainfo, but I'm stuck on this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ankka/Downloads/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    fileInfo = MediaInfo.parse(o)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymediainfo\__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    p = Popen(command, stdout=fp_out, stderr=fp_err, env=environment)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I get this error with this code:

```
from pymediainfo import MediaInfo

o = "D:/Zeluge/video.mkv"

fileInfo = MediaInfo.parse(o)
for track in fileInfo.tracks:
   if track.track_type == "Video":
       print(o)
```

Comment: do you have `mediainfo.exe` installed?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed.

Comment: what happens if you call: `subprocess.check_call(["mediainfo", "--version"])`?

Comment: It does give the same FileNotFoundError.

Comment: what happens if you provide the full path to `mediainfo` including the file extension? Note: you could use raw-string literals such as `r"C:\Some\Path"` (notice: `r''`) -- no need to use `/` here.

Comment: You mean like this?
    subprocess.check_call([r"C:\Program Files\MediaInfo\MediaInfo.exe", "--version"]) 

It opens the program

Comment: try `os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + os.pathsep + r"C:\Program Files\MediaInfo"` before calling `MediaInfo.parse()`.

Comment: Now the code on my original post opens the program and doesn't print anything, until I close the program, then it gives `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Comment: it is a separate question. Check whether you have followed the installation instructions properly (e.g., install `lxml`). It seems like pymediainfo issue.